# The argument type 'List<String>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<String>Function()'

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Map that consists of a String key and a List value. However when I try to add a new value to the Map, I get the error "The argument type 'List' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ListFunction()'".

The sample code is as follows:

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new Map<String, List<String>>();
String key = "Key1";
List<String> currentValues = [];

map.putIfAbsent(key,currentValues);
```

The last line throws the error above. Does anyone have a fix for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the docs](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.1/dart-core/Map/putIfAbsent.html), `putIfAbsent` takes a function as a second argument. So you should write something like this :

```dart
map.putIfAbsent(key, () => currentValues);
```